# struts form property validate="true"

Tags: struts2

How to validate a struts form loaded from ajax using form property validate="true"? (Maybe is better way than copy generated javascript in function that do submit form))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<s:form validate="true">
</sform>
```

is only useful, if you wanna do client validation, which only works with theme xhtml/ajax.

here is a link to explain how to implement client validation with struts2, i hope it helps you.

[struts2 form vlidation](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/client-validation.html)